# IMFByteStream QueryInterface to get IMFAttributes

Tags: video, c++-cx, ms-media-foundation

I wanted to open a video file using `IMFSourceResolver` but it returned The Byte Stream Type of the Given URL is unsupported. What I did is that open the video to get `IRandomAccessStream`, convert it to `IMFByteStream` and use `CreateObjectFromByteStream()` to get the `IMFMediaSource`.

According to this link [CreateObjectFromByteStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says if `MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE` is returned Specify the MIME type by setting the `MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE` attribute on the byte stream. This link for [MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says To get the attribute value, query the byte stream object for the `IMFAttributes` interface. But I could not figure it out how to do that.

Is it possible to get `IMFAttribute` interface from `IMFByteStream`? If so how? And what should the values `MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To find out
>   whether a byte stream supports attributes, query the byte stream
>   object for the IMFAttributes interface.

According to this info, some byte-streams support *IMFAttributes*, others don't. If you query your *IMFByteStream* for *IMFAttributes* and it returns *E_NOINTERFACE* this will mean that yours **doesn't**.

Comment: So if your IMFByteStream objects doesn't support attributes, you can't set arbitrary MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE. Try to create the stream another way, maybe the factory function you are using doesn't create byte stream with attribute support. I'm not familiar with WinRT so I can't really help.